# Is there a way to create a menu bar that sticks but has different content when a button is click

Tags: html

I want to do is create a menu bar that every time a button is click that menu bar is still in there and the content will change.

So the question is do I need to create another page that has that menu bar's code or is there any other way?

Edit: 
[This is what I've done so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBd2t.jpg)
I want to do is like the Facebook's menu bar. The profile, home, messages is still there everytime i go to another page

Comment: Please attach what you have done till now and where exactly you are getting problem. Without code pointers, it is very difficult to help. Attch you page screenshot and upload the html snippet.

Comment: @PriyaJain Sorry. I put the picture now.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to do this.

The simplest option is to toggle classes. Something like `menu-first--inactive` and `menu-second--active` or how you feel comfortable.